# sublimetext 3 - running specific application with system build or use something else?

Tags: shell, subprocess, sublimetext3

I want to be able to run specific application form within sublimetext. It looks like system build tool could be used here, but I can't make it run.

Normally I can run this from terminal, for example (some args/flags can be ignored for application to run, but just demonstrating it how I would normally run it):

```
cd /home/oerp/openerp80/odoo
python odoo.py --xmlrpc-port=8078 --addons-path=~/openerp80/addons,~/openerp80/community-addons,~/openerp80/odoo/addons --db_port=5433 -d db_name -u module_name --test-enable
```

Now I want to mimic same approach from within sublimetext, but I just get error.

I have created custom build:

```
{
    "cmd": [
        "/usr/bin/python2.7", "odoo.py",
        "--xmlrpc-port=8078",
        "--addons-path=~/openerp80/addons,~/openerp80/community-addons,~/openerp80/odoo/addons",
        "--db-port=5433",
        ],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "working_dir": "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/"

}
```

So in console, I get this output:

```
Running /usr/bin/python2.7 odoo.py --xmlrpc-port=8078 --addons-path=~/openerp80/addons,~/openerp80/community-addons,~/openerp80/odoo/addons --db-port=5433
```

And then I see in bottom of sublime, notification that 'Build Finished'. But in reality nothing happens. Odoo application does not start and I could actually write incorrect command and it still says that build was finished.

So can anyone tell if this is how I should use 'Build System' tool or it is not capable of actually running applications and producing log output (like for example you can do in Pycharm: you define shell configuration, somewhat similar as with this build and then can run/stop it like you would do in actual shell).

Maybe there is some other tool (or plugin) in sublimetext that is meant to handle such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully write custom build, so it would run Odoo application the way I wanted. Here is the configuration if someone needs it too:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u odoo.py --db_port=5433",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "working_dir": "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

}
```

It seems using `shell_cmd` does the trick. I copied most of config from python builtin system build.

Oh and this `"show_panel_on_build"` must be set to true if you want to see actual output in sublime console, when you run it.